# Using record separators in awk

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk

I have

```
$ cat awktestf 
a++
b++
c++
```

I am doing and I get

```
cat  awktestf | awk 'BEGIN { RS="++" ; OFS="@"; ORS="()" } { print $0 } END {print "I am done" }'
a()
b()
c()
()I am done()abc@abc:~$
```

My question is why am I getting an extra () at the end?

Even this does not work:

```
$ echo 'a++
> b++
> c++' | awk 'BEGIN { RS="++" ; OFS="@"; ORS="()" } { print $0 } END {print "I am done" }'
a()
b()
c()
()I am done()abc@abc:~$
```

Comment: Note that a) those are Record Separators, not Field Separators, 2) use of a multi-character RS makes your script gawk-specific, 3) you don't need to use cat to open the file, awk can do it by itself, and 4) "print $0" is the default action so you could have just said "{print}" or even the common, idiomatic "1".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ORS` is appended to the end of each output record. Hence your "I am done" ends with `()`.

---

Misunderstood the question the first time.

This

```
a++
b++
c++
```

translates to

```
a++\nb++\nc++\n
```

After splitting into records using `RS`, you get these records

1. a
2. \nb
3. \nc
4. \n

When you print them, each record is terminated with `ORS`, `()`, so

```
a()\nb()\nc()\n()
```

You added "I am done"

```
a()\nb()\nc()\n()I am done()
```

Hence this is displayed as

```
a()
b()
c()
()I am done()
```

(Since the last line does not end with a newline, your prompt shows on the same line)

Comment: I am not talking about that (). I am talking about the () at the beginning of "I am done"

Comment: @abc: Actually there is. `echo` adds a newline to the end by default. That's why when you run `echo "Something"`, your prompt appears on the next line. `echo -n` is used to suppress this behaviour (if the version `echo` supports options).

Comment: +1 nice answer. The newline can be handled with `RS="++\n"`, but then you will need a newline in the ORS: `ORS="()\n"`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have a blank line at the end of the your file.

Since `OFS` is set to `()`, it gets printed after every line that's printed to the output. Just remove the blank line from your input file.

Side note: you don't have to `cat` the file then pipe to awk. Simply use `awk`:

```
awk ' .... ' file
```

Comment: There is no blank line in my input file. I added another example above.

Comment: @abc `OFS` is the reason. When you print `I am done` there's a `\n` at the end of it which is replaced by `OFS` as you told it to do.

Comment: @KingsIndian: ITYM ORS not OFS and there never was a \n to be replaced, the ORS was simply printed at the end of the record.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the clarification. I somehow didn't exaplain it properly although I know ORS is the reason for printing it after each line :)